# How to instantiate in onCreate without declare it final

Tags: android

With this code I have to instantiate the textview at `done` function , How I can declare the textview in onCreate without declare it final?

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    DataQuery query = DataQuery.get("id");
    query.getInBackground(object_id, new GetCallback<DataObject>() {
        TextView data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data);


        @Override
        public void done(DataObject object, DataException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                data.setText((String)object.m_properties.get("data"));

            } 
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried moving your TextView into the `done()`? FYI, using final just ensures you can't re-assign its reference.

Comment: maintain a global variable of TextVewi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Šime Tokić said, you would declare it as a member variable. That would look something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    ...
}
```

This is common practice for UI components in Android anyway in case you ever needed to access the component elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a member variable of class MyActivity.

Comment: This should be in the comments rather than as an answer.